# Regular expressions counting length of word if it has a 'w' letter. Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a stack of words and I need to get the longest words which has 'w' letter in it. I've done it this way

```
public static boolean longestWWord(String s)
{
    boolean hasw=false;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)=='w')
        {
            hasw = true;
        }
    }
    return hasw;
}
    System.out.println("Word with maximum 'w' chareckters : ");
    int counter =0;
    String word="";
    for ( String ss : arr) {
        if(longestWWord(ss)){
            if(ss.length()>counter)
            {
                counter = ss.length();
                word = ss;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(word);
```

But now i have a task to find if the word has 'w' in it and the length of that word using regular expressinos. Please help me

Comment: I don't understand. Aren't you doing that already? Why you need to use regex?

Comment: Why do you need that method `longestWWord()`? is it not doing what [`String.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) does already?

Comment: You can find words with "`w`" (that you will need to escape) with regular expressions but for length you will still use the same method.

Comment: I have a task to do it using regex

Comment: So how to find if word has 'w' in it ? with regex

Comment: Did you Google for "regular expression"?  There's lots of documentation out there for how to write regexes.  Come back when you've actually tried and had it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MatcherTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = "wata what word down a adf asdfasdf";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*[wW]+\\w*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(word);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

will output:

```
wata
what
word
down
```

You can find documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Answer (score 0):

this `\b[a-zA-Z0-9]*[wW][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b` regex will match all the words with w or W in it
Pass the matching words to the function to find the length. And in java you have to escape backSlash like

`\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]*[wW][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\b`

Comment: isn't it way too much regex for such a simple task? he already has words, no need to look for word boundary and stuff